# Azure Active Directory (AAD) adhoc authentication

Tags: azure

In Azure Active Directory, how can I enable/disable the adhoc authentication? 
Is there a way to do it thru the portal?
thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there’s no way of doing It from the portal. However, you can use the Azure Powershell for sending simple, one line commands to control that.
Try using below and kindly let me know how it goes.

```
Set-MsolCompanySettings -AllowEmailVerifiedUsers $false
```

Hope this helps.